# grizzly jaxws schemaLocation

Tags: jax-ws, grizzly

i'm publishing a soap ws api from within my java app.
so far i've used the jdk built-in http server, like so:

Endpoint.publish("http://www.example.com:80/soap/v1/foo", myWebService);

and all worked fine.

now switching to grizzly. my code is based on the official example from http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.0/html/jaxws-samples.html

thus something like 
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(httpHandler, "/soap/v1/foo");

the wsdl is available for both under the expected url http://www.example.com:80/soap/v1/foo?wsdl but with grizzly the generated wsdl looks different. the schmemaLocation is shortened in all places in that the "/v1/foo" part is removed, it only points to /soap. this is the case for all services that i publish (multiple). and the result is that the methods can't be called.

(i'll cross-post this on the grizzly mailing users list, although there isn't much traffic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been fixed in Grizzly 2.2.5